# Making the Comment Count on my site link to the post link or comments area

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I recently updated my comments code via [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-ultimate-guide-to-implementing-facebook-comments-on-your-blog--wp-23855). I replaced the default comments_popup_link with the following code. This works great in displaying the real comment count (FB comments + WP comments), however, I can't figure out a way to get the comment count text to link to the post permalink. Any advice?

```
<span class="comments-link">
<?php 
    $commentCount = full_comment_count();
    if ( $commentCount == 0 ) {
        echo '<post-date>- Leave a comment</post-date>'; 
    } 
    else if ( $commentCount == 1 ) {
        echo '<post-date>- One comment</post-date>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<post-date>- ' . $commentCount . ' comments</post-date>'; 
} 
?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this way you'll be able to link to your comments

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>/#comments">

<span class="comments-link">
<?php 
    $commentCount = full_comment_count();
    if ( $commentCount == 0 ) {
        echo '<post-date>- Leave a comment</post-date>'; 
    } 
    else if ( $commentCount == 1 ) {
        echo '<post-date>- One comment</post-date>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<post-date>- ' . $commentCount . ' comments</post-date>'; 
} 
?>
</span>
</a>
```

Comment: If not, change the first line to: `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>/.comments-link">`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your first answer did the trick! I can't thank you enough...this was driving me crazy!

Comment: No problem @user3696987. Glad that helped you :)
Consider marking this answer as correct. Regards